# Select from pg_settings is very slow

Tags: postgresql, pg-settings

Recently I installed PostgreSQL 12.1 and I found that installation of  application takes minutes (when previously it was seconds).

I found, that during initialization of database there are a lot of queries to get values from pg_catalog.pg_settings and they are really slow.

Simple `SELECT * from pg_catalog.pg_settings` takes 0.6 seconds.

Anyone have any ideas why this query takes so long?

UPD:

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from pg_catalog.pg_settings;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on pg_show_all_settings a  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=485) (actual time=453.832..453.870 rows=314 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.077 ms
 Execution Time: 453.929 ms
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Please run `set track_io_timing = on; explain (analyze, buffers, timing) select ...;` then show us that execution plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see a plan below:
`set track_io_timing = on; explain (analyze, buffers, timing) SELECT * from pg_catalog.pg_settings;
SET
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on pg_show_all_settings a  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=485) (actual time=464.334..464.365 rows=314 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.236 ms
 Execution Time: 464.570 ms
(3 rows)`

Comment: I would `strace` the backend process. Do you have any extensions installed that define custom parameters?

Comment: No, no extensions. I did just a fresh install.

Comment: That is definitely unexpected (I get about 1ms).  What OS are you using?  How did you install?  What non-default settings are in postgresql.conf?

Comment: I use windows 10 pro. Used msi file to install. All settings are default.

Comment: Any updates on the issue? We've got the same poor performance after updating to pg12 from pg9.5. Selecting single setting from pg_settings takes ~800ms.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed in PostgreSQL v12.8.2.

Please see
[Selecting from pg_catalog.pg_settings got slow after updating to PostgreSQL 12 (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69492514/selecting-from-pg-catalog-pg-settings-got-slow-after-updating-to-postgresql-12/69497133#69497133) for details.