# Selecting from pg_catalog.pg_settings got slow after updating to PostgreSQL 12 (windows)

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-12

We have noticed a severe decrease in performance reading
pg_catalog.pg_settings table in PostgreSQL 12 on MS Windows 10  machines compared to earlier versions.

```
explain (analyze, buffers, timing)
SELECT * from pg_catalog.pg_settings where name =
'standard_conforming_strings';
```

On **PostgreSQL 12.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit:**

```
Function Scan on pg_show_all_settings a  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=5
width=485) (actual time=343.350..343.356 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (name = 'standard_conforming_strings'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 313
Planning Time: 0.079 ms
Execution Time: 343.397 ms
```

Compare to **PostgreSQL 11.13, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit**:

```
Function Scan on pg_show_all_settings a  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=5
width=485) (actual time=0.723..0.728 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (name = 'standard_conforming_strings'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 289
Planning Time: 0.125 ms
Execution Time: 0.796 ms
```

This is standard installation, the changed parameters are:

```
SELECT name, current_setting(name), source
FROM pg_settings
WHERE source NOT IN ('default', 'override');
```

| name | current_setting | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| client_encoding | UTF8 | client |
| DateStyle | ISO, YMD | client |
| default_text_search_config | pg_catalog.simple | session |
| default_transaction_isolation | read committed | session |
| dynamic_shared_memory_type | windows | configuration file |
| extra_float_digits | 3 | session |
| lc_messages | Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257 | configuration file |
| lc_monetary | Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257 | configuration file |
| lc_numeric | Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257 | configuration file |
| lc_time | Lithuanian_Lithuania.1257 | configuration file |
| listen_addresses | * | configuration file |
| log_destination | stderr | configuration file |
| log_file_mode | 0640 | configuration file |
| log_timezone | Europe/Helsinki | configuration file |
| logging_collector | on | configuration file |
| max_connections | 100 | configuration file |
| max_stack_depth | 2MB | environment variable |
| max_wal_size | 1GB | configuration file |
| min_wal_size | 80MB | configuration file |
| port | 5444 | configuration file |
| search_path | "$user", public | session |
| shared_buffers | 128MB | configuration file |
| TimeZone | Europe/Helsinki | client |

The slowing down is observed on **MS Windows 10 machines only**. We have pg12
on linux (PostgreSQL 12.6 (Debian 12.6-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit ) that doesn't show any
decrease in performance.

I've tested different versions and it seems the problem appeared on PG12,
earlier versions up to PG11 work ok. PG13 also suffers from low reading
speed of `pg_settings`.

The behaviour is reproduced on 3 different machines (2 virtual and one
physical, different hardware).

What is the cause of this? How to fix the issue?

I've found a similar question [Select from pg_settings is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657909/select-from-pg-settings-is-very-slow#comment122812294_59657909) but it still has no answer too.

**UPDATE**

I've tested PostgreSQL 14 - there is a noticible performance increase.
**PostgreSQL 14.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit**:

```
Function Scan on pg_show_all_settings a  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=5 width=485) (actual time=8.502..8.508 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (name = 'standard_conforming_strings'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 343
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=18
Planning Time: 0.224 ms
Execution Time: 8.555 ms
```

It is still 10 times slower than the PostgreSQL 11.13 but 40 times faster than the Pg12.

**EDIT 2**

As noticed by **a_horse_with_no_name** we don't observe performance problems when using querying `current_setting`.

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers, timing) 
select current_setting('standard_conforming_strings');
```

returns:

```
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.025 ms
Execution Time: 0.022 ms
```

Comment: Why is this a problem?  While I agree that 300ms (or even 10ms) for such a query is quite slow, this is nothing that I would expect to be critical. Or are you running this hundreds of times per second?

Comment: Interesting enough on Windows 10 with Postgres 14, I get around 8-10ms for the query in the question (tried a few times), but I consistently get runtimes of about 0.02ms for `select current_setting('standard_conforming_strings');`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - 300ms is critical as the third party components ([ZeosLib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/)) do several `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'some_setting'` requests when connecting to the server. Because of this - connecting to DB server became a very costly action (takes ~2 seconds). This is a big issue for us.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe thank You for trying it out. On my machine I have `Execution Time: 332.883 ms` and it is pretty stable on pg12. I tried using psql to be sure the pg_settings are not accessed by the client - the planning time is grater the first time (0.213ms) and later it drops to 0.067ms. The execution time is around 330ms all the time.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe - it is no problem **IF** you use a connection pool :). We don't use pooling internally and using PgBouncer will not help as the components will still query the pg_settings table when connecting. But yes - pooling would help, thank You for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted the question to the `pgsql-performance` mailing list and got an answer from Ranier Vilela that updating to latest version of PostgreSQL (v12.8.2) should fix the problem.

He directed me to a [message thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/MN2PR15MB2560D77DFB58BD893E2EAAAD85C29%40MN2PR15MB2560.namprd15.prod.outlook.com) discussing the issue. It seems the problem was in `libintl` library and is now fixed.